# java.lang.NullPointerException org.user.SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:31)

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I am trying to learn the JSP but I have implemented a simple project to check how JSP works but I am getting the following error when I run the application on the the server. To see something I have to enter a username in the link as:

http://localhost:8082/SimpleServletProject_6_passing_more_parameters/SimpleServletPath?userName=alex

but when typing the link without userName

/SimpleServletProject_6_passing_more_parameters/SimpleServletPath

I am getting the error below.

**The SimpleServlet class:**

```
package org.user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SimpleServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "A simple servlet", urlPatterns = { "/SimpleServletPath" })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (!userName.isEmpty() && userName != null) {

            session.setAttribute("savedNameUser", userName);

        }
        writer.println("Request parameter has username as  " + userName);
        writer.println("Session parameter has username as  "
                + (String) session.getAttribute("savedNameUser"));

    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleServletProject_6_passing_more_parameters' did not find a matching property.
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Apr 11 2016 07:57:09 UTC
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         7.0.69.0
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            6.3
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_74-b02
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         G:\eclipse_workspace\Java_JSP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=G:\eclipse_workspace\Java_JSP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=G:\eclipse_workspace\Java_JSP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_74/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_74/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_74/lib/amd64;C:\xampp\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;;G:\eclipse\eclipse for dynamic web\eclipse;;.
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 942 ms
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 1175 ms
Mai 28, 2016 9:14:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.user.SimpleServlet] in context with path [/SimpleServletProject_6_passing_more_parameters] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.user.SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SimpleServletProject_6_passing_more_parameters</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Comment: can u print stacktrace??

Comment: and that link is valid only on your local machine

Comment: @holidayCoder: I added it.

Comment: You will get error as you are not setting userName, so request.getParameter("userName") points to null.

Comment: just change your if statement to short-circuit on the null.  put the null check first.

Comment: that won't solve anything @DMoses and please post your web.xml because `500` is only internal server error and therefore check your `servlet mapping` @shaileshYadav

Comment: @holidayCoder in most webservers if you don't catch an exception it gets returned as a 500 error.  The NPE isn't being caught and thus the 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking is the username isn't empty before checking is it's `null`. If it's really `null`, the call to `isEmpty()` will fail with a `NullPointerException`. Just switch the checks around:

```
if (userName != null && !userName.isEmpty()) {
    // code
```

Or if you can use Apache Commons Lang, you could use [`StringUtils#isEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) for a more elegant outcome:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
    // code
```

Comment: @holidayCoder `500` - **Internal Server Error** which is a typical error throws by a application server when something when wrong within the server-side :)